# Generator to run a compact industrial VFD (Sinamics V20)

Tags: generator, induction-motor, vfd

[image][image]

I have a Siemens Sinamics V20 (0.5HP) industrial VFD (as picture), powering a 3-phase 0.25 HP electric motor.

I work in the field and generator is the only way to have electric power.

I am looking for a 3.6 kVA generator with AVR technology. Do you guys think it will work ok?

Edit: OBS:
My equipment works like a Piling Machine. Sometimes he lifts the hammer sometimes releases it (10kg hammer)
The 3 phase motor have a mechanical reducer (1:60).

Comment: If you're going to use a generator then why do you need an inverter?

Comment: Or by "inverter" do you mean VFD (variable frequency drive)?

Comment: Sorry... by inverter I mean the VFD (as shown in picture)..

Comment: The VFD won’t care about the input frequency but it may get upset if the voltage droops or overshoots too much. This might occur if the load changes on the generator - as in other devices connected.

Comment: What sort of AVR? it could get messy of the  gererator itself has an inverter output

Comment: @Jasen it just says "AVR" at the generator spec. My VFD says it can work with +/-10% of voltage variation, but I do not know if this is the same range of the output of the generator.

Comment: With that much overdimensioning of your genset, you should be fine.

Comment: Ok! thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the VFD and the generator will probably work properly. However the VFD will have some harmonic content in its input current. That will cause harmonic voltage in the generator output that could cause difficulty with other loads connected to the generator. However the 3.6 kVA generator is like enough larger than the 0.25 kVA VFD load to prevent that. Check to see what Siemens recommends about using input reactors to reduce harmonic currents drawn by the VFD.

Harmonic distortion of the load voltage caused by the VFD could adversely effect the generator AVR, but the low ratio of VFD kVA load to generator kVA rating should prevent that.

A generator with an inverter output could have a sufficiently distorted output waveform to adversely effect VFD operation. However that would be problematic for a many types of loads, so a reasonably decent quality generator of that type should not cause a problem.

Comment: Hello Charles, thank you for your answer. Actually I do not know the VFD kVa. How can i check this? I have the Input information (6.2A) and the voltage is 220V. 
Do you think the "+/- 10%" range of the VFD is compatible with the distorsion range of the output voltage of generator?

OBS: My equipment works like a Piling Machine. Sometimes he lifts the hammer sometimes releases it.

Comment: For the purpose of determining that the VFD load is much smaller than the  generator capacity, it is sufficient to assume 1 kVA per Hp of driven motor rating. Calculating using the VFD input current rating gives about the same answer. The +/- 10% voltage range should be compatible with any reasonably acceptable quality generator.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Cowie! I am going to test it and than I post the results here